# Resolution in Interpolation Scheme

Tags: metpy

I have a grid template that has grid spacing in hundredths of a degree instead of meters since the projection is lat-lon.  What are my options for the hres parameter with the interpolate_to_grid tool/program ?  Is it restricted to a value in meters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `hres` parameter to `interpolate_to_grid` just needs to be in the same units as the `x` and `y` parameters, so specifying the resolution in degrees will be fine. This comes with the caveat that `interpolate_to_grid` assumes it is working with points on a plane, so the lons/lats you pass in will be treated as planar Cartesian coordinates, not coordinates on a sphere.

If you need to interpolate to a specific set of points, you may want to look instead at [`interpolate_to_points`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.interpolate.interpolate_to_points.html). This function can interpolate to an arbitrary set of points, so you could take a grid, reshape it to a 1D set of points, and pass it to that function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think interpolate_to_points sounds like the program I need.  This should solve my problem. I will report back if I have any other issues.